# Python 3.6: How do I zfill numbers within a generated list?

Tags: python-3.x

My program is designed to generate numbers for a lottery ticket. I want single digit numbers to be filled with a zero in the front. e.g. 02. I've tried `zfill(2)`, and `'.02d'` in various ways but still can't find what I'm doing wrong.

```
from random import randint, sample
lotteryNumbers = []

for number in range(0,10):
    lotteryNumbers.append(sorted(sample(range(69), 5)))
    r = randint(1,26)
    lotteryNumbers[number].append('PB: ' +str(r))

print(' QP','A.', format(lotteryNumbers[0], '02d'))
print(' QP','B.', format(lotteryNumbers[1]))
# TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `lotteryNumbers` elements are heterogeneous lists of 5 numbers a *string*, for example:

```
>>> lotteryNumbers[0]
[11, 52, 54, 61, 68, 'PB: 8']
```

But the built-in `format` function, using '02d' format spec, works on numbers.  It does not work on lists.

```
>>> format(8, '02d')
'08'
>>> format([8], '02d')
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__
```

My recommendation is to **store only numbers in the lists**, i.e. make the data homogeneous, and then **write a separate function for displaying/formatting the data**. This function should accept a list of numbers as input.

See https://pyformat.info for a good resource about string formatting in Python.